# Typescript - Class type in generics gives error when trying to instantiate it

Tags: typescript

Let's say that I have this class:

```js
export abstract class BytesView<T> {
    constructor(protected _buffer: T) {}

    get buffer(): T {
        return this._buffer;
    }
    set buffer(value: T) {
        this._buffer = value;
    }

    abstract get length(): number;
}
```

which is extended by these two classes:

```js
export class BufferView extends BytesView<Buffer> {
    get length(): number {
        return this._buffer.length;
    }
}

export class ArrayBufferView extends BytesView<ArrayBuffer> {
    get length(): number {
        return this._buffer.byteLength;
    }
}
```

Now I have this class that uses Generics and tries to use them:

```js
export class MyClass<B, V extends BytesView<B>> {
    private readonly _bytesView: V;

    constructor(buffer: B) {
        this._bytesView = new V(buffer); // I get an error in this line
    }
}
```

In the line with `new V(buffer)` I get an error:

```
'V' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts (2693)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a new buffer view class that handles a buffer of type `B`. This is a runtime behavior.

Typescript does not use generic types to compile Javascript that fulfills this use case. You will have to determine the type of the buffer in order to instantiate the appropriate buffer view class.

```
class MyClass<B> {
    private readonly _bytesView: BytesView<unknown> | undefined;

    constructor(buffer: B) {
      if (buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        this._bytesView = new ArrayBufferView(buffer);
      } else if (Array.isArray(buffer)) {
        this._bytesView = new BufferView(buffer);
      }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=2&pln=29&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQgTwgUzADUBLPAdwB4AVAPgQG8BYAKATaQHsA7SKAV3gcoACgAOUDvnh4AJggD6IPgDNleKAC4EVAJQMAvixbsEAczyIlq9cJ1aqDYyfZQLfKFwQQAFsTAA6RRU1KABuJzZDVnYwCwQrEOEAN2BkPjx7PSZo5y9fAKDrKAQAXgQUtLxwnIQoiIRQXjhEc0RkPC5TH1stLj4AWxB1arrmAHoxhBk8FGAoYk6GqBBiaDnsLGD1L2xRPBYIXbxNotKEAEEoGGwKPsH1GmqWWfQTkJJyBDwAD3wuGQwOHwRFIlEwWygdGyJlaCHanW6dgQdyGxWhuQQrgg7k8Pj8gQS6n88K63mqJiioxeGEu13BRQ+ZC+vw6AKwuAIjIotOA2HpISh9VhJMRvQGqMcNRMWJxeXxhRC-hAHIAMh1SeT2JSjMxqQgALLYADCqHQFEwgpq4mIKXwmLwwBk3GQG0UHJB5C0QM5oIofC4AGsuBwyFw6AAfBD+6bKBayJ41WDcXgCCBCYSEzRYLL1NjEZQIDMQhALSDALiwPAcAs8vkQnNS9h4grK4GMs5cT61-nqRlFoo6TUUr7IWIlgvCWv+Py1-shHQNjFylvu9tlTtMntQPuZwe52r1SlAA)

Comment: You are right, but my class is a base for two other packages. One is with ArrayBuffer, so it is for the web. The other one is for Buffer, so for nodejs. If I add in typescript these two types, the other two packages won't work anymore, nodejs will say that there is no ArrayBuffer and web will say that there is no Buffer